# wpdb->prepare() returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I can't figure out why this is returning "NULL". I've hardcoded the date/time string in to the $scheduledDates variable. In practice that's user input. Everything works fine when I don't prepare the query.

```
$scheduledDate = "2015-09-01 00:00:00";

$queryString = "SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE event_start > %s AND event_start < %s + INTERVAL 1 DAY";

$scheduled_blocks = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $queryString, $scheduledDate ) );
```

The code below works fine, whether I hard code the date/time or not...

```
$scheduledDate = $_POST['scheduledDate'];

$scheduled_blocks = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE event_start > "' . $scheduledDate . '" AND event_start < "' . $scheduledDate . '" + INTERVAL 1 DAY');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$wpdb->print_error()` to see what errors you get. By the look of your code though, I think the number of placeholders have to be the same as the amount of values you're supplying to the `prepare` method. Alter your call to this:

```
$wpdb->prepare($queryString, $scheduledDate, $scheduledDate)
```

Comment: Gah, of course. That worked! Thank you on both counts!